# Users hierarchy

Tags: user, hierarchy

I can't find how to create an Users hierarchy. I have several users in SalesForce and I want to create a hierarchy. For example, I will have Developers and Manager. I want to attach some Developers to a Manager and in a custom page where I list all users, the Manager could see all the Developers attached to him and Developers can see only himself.

If I query on users to display them, I'm wondering how only users I can see can be returned ?

Is there possible to achieve that in SalesForce ? I try to do it with Roles and Territory Management without success.

Comment: Do you want to fetch user below in role hierarchy using query... ?

Comment: Yes, that's the aim.  I have a list where I display all users at the moment. But the final goal is to only display users attach to connected user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here's 3 ways to do this:

1. role hierarchy which I do believe you can access from Apex (haven't tried this myself). You'd want to do this if some objects have a private sharing setting and this aligns with certain  visibility requirements between these developers and managers.
2. User the manager standard field on the user record if you aren't already using this.
3. Add a [Hierarchical lookup](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm) custom field to the user object called 'Dev Manager'.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:
//=======================================

```
Group groupListRS = [SELECT id,name,Type,DeveloperName,relatedid FROM Group where Type='Role' AND DeveloperName ='CEOA'];

Set<id> allSubRoleIds = new set<id>();
  allSubRoleIds   = getAllSubRoleIds(new Set<ID>{groupListRS.relatedId});
public Set<ID> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<ID> MainRoleId) {


                        Set<ID> subRoleIds = new Set<ID>();

                        for(UserRole userRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId = :MainroleId AND ParentRoleID != null]) {
                            subRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);
                        }   

                        if(subRoleIds.size() > 0) {
                                subRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(subRoleIds));
                        }

                            return subRoleids;

 }

list<user> uss = [select id,name from user where UserRoleId in :allsubRoleIds];
system.debug(uss);
```

Group table contain set of user, if you want to fetch information regarding Role, group, RoleAndSubordinates, Queue.
I am using 3 query here

```
1.  SELECT id,name,Type,DeveloperName,relatedid FROM Group where Type='Role' AND DeveloperName =’CEOA’  //specific Role(append A in Standard Role)
2.  select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId = :MainroleId
3.  select id,name from user where UserRoleId in :allsubRoleIds
```

Group Table having relatedId column, and this relatedId stores in Userrole Table in ParentRoleId.
UserRole  User(userRoleId)  // relation between UserRole and User

And I am calling getAllSubRoleIds method recursively it gives all users Id of userRole who has the parentRoleId = relatedId from Group, than pass all these id into user object query where UserRoleId = above collection of Ids, it gives all the user’s id below specific Role.

Comment: Amit this aswer may be more easier to understand if you also explain the code you're written.

Comment: Hello @Samuel De Rycke,  I have a basic idea regarding this. I have add some description in my answer. May this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly by querying User role the following code will cycle through the user roles and get everyone in the current users role and below. Please note that in order to prevent to many SOQL queries I have a limit on the number of times the query executes. For most orgs this will be sifficient but if you have more than 10 levels you may have to adjust it:

```
public static selectOption[] populateAvailUsers(){

        SelectOption[] alias = New SelectOption[]{};
        Map<String,ID> mUsers = New Map<String,ID>();
        Set<ID> roleIDs = New Set<ID>{userInfo.getUserRoleID()};
        Integer MAX = 10;
        String[] uNames = New String[]{};

        String qry = 'Select ID, Name, UserRoleID from User Where isActive = true';

            qry += ' AND UserRole.parentRoleID IN :roleIDs'; 

        for(Integer x=0 ; x<MAX;x++){
            for(user u : database.query(qry)){
                mUsers.put(u.name,u.id); //Stores the results
                roleIDs.add(u.UserRoleID); //Keeps track of the roles needing to query for child roles
            }
        }


        uNames.addAll(mUsers.keySet()); //Sort names alpha
        uNames.sort();

        for(String s : uNames)  //Create select options  
            alias.add(New SelectOption(mUsers.get(s),s));

        return alias;


}
```