# Find users under a node in role hierarchy

Tags: apex, soql, user, role-hierarchy

We have a multi level role hierarchy. I need to find all the users directly under a role and its sub-roles in a role hierarchy. How can this be achieved efficiently using SOQL or Apex or any other way ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81603/users-hierarchy/81704#81704 - be mindful of query limits etc but you could adapt it to what you want to do.

Comment: @Eric IMO It is not that hard to do all processing of `UserRole` with one query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would get the `UserRole` records you want first and then query the `User` records.

**Grouping UserRole Records by Parent**

```
// public with sharing class RoleHierarchy
static Map<Id, List<UserRole>> hierarchy
{
    get
    {
        if (hierarchy == null)
        {
            hierarchy = new Map<Id, List<UserRole>>();
            for (UserRole role : [SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole])
            {
                if (!hierarchy.containsKey(role.ParentRoleId))
                    hierarchy.put(role.ParentRoleId, new List<UserRole>());
                hierarchy.get(role.ParentRoleId).add(role);
            }
        }
        return hierarchy;
    }
    private set;
}
```

**Getting Relevant UserRole Records**

```
// public with sharing class RoleHierarchy
public static List<UserRole> getChildren(Id userRoleId)
{
    return hierarchy.containsKey(userRoleId) ?
        hierarchy.get(userRoleId) : new List<UserRole>();
}

// I would just use one of the below and name it getSubHierarchy
// Not entirely clear based on OP if top-level should be included

public static Set<Id> getSubHierarchyInclusive(Id userRoleId)
{
    Set<Id> roleIds = new Set<Id> { userRoleId };
    for (UserRole childRole : getChildren(userRoleId))
        roleIds.addAll(getSubHierarchyInclusive(childRole.Id));
    return roleIds;
}
public static Set<Id> getSubHierarchyExclusive(Id userRoleId)
{
    Set<Id> roleIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (UserRole childRole : getChildren(userRoleId))
    {
        roleIds.add(childRole.Id);
        roleIds.addAll(getSubHierarchyExclusive(childRole.Id));
    }
    return roleIds;
}
```

**Get Users**

```
// public with sharing class RoleHierarchy
public static List<User> getUsersUnder(Id userRoleId)
{
    return [
        SELECT Id FROM User
        WHERE UserRoleId IN :getSubHierarchy(userRoleId)
    ];
}
```

**The above approach consumes a total of 2 `SOQL` statements.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated code of Adrian Larson
Added :

- IsActive as criteria ( because assigning a Task to a inactive user fails for example )
- missing brackets/parenthesis :)

  ```
  // public with sharing class RoleHierarchy
  global static Map<Id, List<UserRole>> hierarchy
  {
      get
      {
          if (hierarchy == null)
          {
              hierarchy = new Map<Id, List<UserRole>>();
              for (UserRole role : [SELECT ParentRoleId FROM UserRole])
              {
                  if (!hierarchy.containsKey(role.ParentRoleId))
                      hierarchy.put(role.ParentRoleId, new List<UserRole>());
                  hierarchy.get(role.ParentRoleId).add(role);
              }
          }
          return hierarchy;
      }
  private set;
  ```

  }

  ```
  // public with sharing class RoleHierarchy
  global static List<UserRole> getChildren(Id userRoleId)
  {
      return hierarchy.containsKey(userRoleId) ?
          hierarchy.get(userRoleId) : new List<UserRole>();
  }

  // I would just use one of the below and name it getSubHierarchy
  // Not entirely clear based on OP if top-level should be included
  global static Set<Id> getSubHierarchyInclusive(Id userRoleId)
  {
      Set<Id> roleIds = new Set<Id> { userRoleId };
          for (UserRole childRole : getChildren(userRoleId))
          roleIds.addAll(getSubHierarchyInclusive(childRole.Id));
      return roleIds;
  }

  global static List<User> getUsersUnder(Id userRoleId)
  {
      return [
          SELECT Id FROM User
          WHERE UserRoleId IN :getSubHierarchyInclusive(userRoleId) AND IsActive=true
      ];
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass a Set of Userrole ids and to code below will return users corresponding to each Userrole id after collecting all users under each subordinates.

```java
public class AllUserRoleQuery {

    public  static Map<Id,List<Id>> GetRoleVsUSerMap(Set<Id> RoleIds){
        Set<Id> RecievedRoleIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> RolesWithoutParentIds = new Set<Id>();  
        Map<Id, Id> RoleVsParentId = new Map<Id, Id>();
        Map<Id, Set<Id>> RoleIdVsParentSeries = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        Map<Id, List<Id>> RoleIdVsUSerList = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

        List<UserRole> AllUserRoleList = new List<UserRole>();
         if(RoleIds != NULL && RoleIds.size() > 0){
            RecievedRoleIds.addAll(RoleIds);

            List<String> Userrolefield = new List<String>{'id','parentroleid'};
            if(UtilCheckCRUD.isAccessible('UserRole',Userrolefield)){

                AllUserRoleList = [Select Id, ParentRoleId From UserRole Limit 10000];

                for(UserRole usrRoleForParent : AllUserRoleList){
                    if(RoleIds.contains(usrRoleForParent.Id)){
                        if(usrRoleForParent.ParentRoleId != NULL){
                            RoleVsParentId.put(usrRoleForParent.Id, usrRoleForParent.ParentRoleId);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Boolean IterateOnceMore = true;

                while(IterateOnceMore){
                    Boolean NewRoleAdded = false;
                    for(UserRole usrRole : AllUserRoleList){
                        if(usrRole.ParentRoleId != NULL && RoleIds.contains(usrRole.ParentRoleId) && !RoleIds.contains(usrRole.Id)){
                            RoleVsParentId.put(usrRole.Id, usrRole.ParentRoleId);
                            RoleIds.add(usrRole.id);
                            NewRoleAdded = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!NewRoleAdded){
                        IterateOnceMore = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Role Id Vs ParentSeries
            for(Id roleId : RoleIds){
                if(!RoleIdVsParentSeries.containsKey(roleId)){
                    Set<Id> setInitialozation = new Set<Id>();
                    RoleIdVsParentSeries.put(roleId, setInitialozation);
                }
                Set<Id> parentSeriesSet = new Set<Id>();
                parentSeriesSet = RoleIdVsParentSeries.get(roleId);
                Id parentId = getParentId(roleId, RoleVsParentId);
                Id TempRoleId = roleId;
                while (parentId != NULL){
                    parentId = getParentId(TempRoleId, RoleVsParentId);
                    if(parentId != NULL){
                        parentSeriesSet.add(parentId);
                        TempRoleId = parentId;
                    }
                }
                if(parentSeriesSet != NULL && parentSeriesSet.size() > 0){
                    RoleIdVsParentSeries.put(roleId, parentSeriesSet);
                }
            }

            if(RoleIds.size() > 0){
                List<User> userList = new List<User>();

                List<String> UserFieldsvalue = new List<String>{'id','userroleid','isactive'};
                if(UtilCheckCRUD.isAccessible('User',UserFieldsvalue)){

                    userList = [Select Id, UserRoleId From User Where UserRoleId In : RoleIds AND IsActive = true AND Name !='Chatter Expert'];
                    if(userList.size() > 0){
                        for(User usr : userList){
                            if(usr.UserRoleId != NULL && RecievedRoleIds.contains(usr.UserRoleId)){
                                if(!RoleIdVsUSerList.containsKey(usr.UserRoleId)){
                                    List<Id> UserListinitialization = new List<Id>();
                                    RoleIdVsUSerList.put(usr.UserRoleId, UserListinitialization);
                                }
                                RoleIdVsUSerList.get(usr.UserRoleId).add(usr.id);
                            }
                            if(usr.UserRoleId != NULL && RoleIdVsParentSeries.containsKey(usr.UserRoleId)){
                                Set<Id> ParentsRoleIds = new Set<Id>();
                                ParentsRoleIds = RoleIdVsParentSeries.get(usr.UserRoleId);
                                if(ParentsRoleIds != NULL && ParentsRoleIds.size() > 0){
                                    for(Id RoleId : ParentsRoleIds){
                                        if(RecievedRoleIds.contains(RoleId)){
                                            if(!RoleIdVsUSerList.containsKey(RoleId)){
                                                List<Id> UserListinitialization = new List<Id>();
                                                RoleIdVsUSerList.put(RoleId, UserListinitialization);
                                            }
                                            RoleIdVsUSerList.get(RoleId).add(usr.id);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        return RoleIdVsUSerList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return RoleIdVsUSerList;
    }

    public static Id getParentId(Id RoleId, Map<Id,Id> RoleVsParentId){
        if(RoleId != NULL && RoleVsParentId != NULL && RoleVsParentId.size() > 0){
            if(RoleVsParentId.containsKey(RoleId) && RoleVsParentId.get(RoleId) != NULL){
                return RoleVsParentId.get(RoleId);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```