# SOQL inside a While loop is not detected in Security review

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, isv, security-scanner

Noticed a weird thing, `SOQL` inside a `for` loop is a bad practice but in a `while` loop isn't?

Force.com security scanner has not detected a `SOQL` inside a while loop and also note that our paid application is already in `AppExchange` for past few years. So I am not sure why security is allowing this.

This is a concern because if same functionality is implemented in recursive function, it might complain.

Code snippet to traverse from child to root parent:

```
List<String> descriptionList = new List<String>();
while(accountId != null) {
    String parentAccount = null;

    for(Account account:[select Name, parentId from Account where id = :accountId]) {
        parentAccount = account.parentId;
        descriptionList.add(account.Name);
    }
    accountId = parentAccount;
}
```

I can do some workaround for to resolve the issue but curious to know on why Salesforce allows it.

Comment: Yeah, a query inside a while loop is bad, but is it a _security_ issue? I haven't really used the security scanner myself, does it complain about queries inside of for loops?

Comment: Its a (long) while since I used the scanner, but the last time I did I got the impression that the scanner was not doing a full parse and analysis of the code but some looser kind of pattern matching. So there were many false positives (that I looked at) and so potentially many false negatives (that I didn't look at).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither PMD nor the Code Scanner consider this pattern to be a code violation for "SOQL inside a loop." That type of rule is more concerned with code that is not bulkified (e.g. using multiple queries when one would suffice) instead of this situation, where you're actually querying recursively, which has legitimate purposes, such as building an hierarchy of records.

Comment: I've never found a need. You can often [build hierarchies with a single query using a `Map<Id, List<SObject>>`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/102733/2995).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, it still requires multiple queries in a "loop", but it's not the same as the type of violation they're looking for (querying records singly instead of aggregating parent/child records into a single query).

Comment: I was under assumption that salesforce doesn’t allow any app to be published on appexchage with any bad practices. Your explanation make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulSharma They strongly recommend having code that performs well. There's nothing inherently "wrong" with the code in the question, although depending on its purpose, there may be a way to reduce the overall number of queries (e.g. by querying multiple levels at once, etc).