# Get a list of child accounts for any given parent account using apex

Tags: soql, query, account, hierarchy, parent

I have a requirement where i have the following need. If the account is a parent account, i need to loop and traverse through each child account and get a list of child accounts at any level deep. Once i get all the child accounts, I need to update all the child accounts with a custom field based on the parent. I am planning to create an account insert or update trigger to do the following. Here is a question.
1. Does any of one you have any sample utility class or method which would loop through all child accounts and return me a collection of child accounts?
2. How do we also make sure that i fire the trigger only once on the parent only and it does not fire on the child also?
Buyan

Answer (score 4):

On question 1), an alternative to the ultimate parent approach is a query per layer:

```
Id accountId = '...';
Account[] allChildren = new Account[] {};
Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>{accountId};
Account[] children;
do {
    children = [select Id, Name from Account where ParentId in :parentIds];
    allChildren.addAll(children);
    parentIds.clear();
    for (Account child : children) parentIds.add(child.Id);
} while (children.size() > 0);
```

On question 2), if you only want the trigger to process root Accounts, only process Accounts that have a `ParentId` field of null.

Comment: Good old `do`/`while`. You could probably use a `SOQL For Loop` to make your `do` block slightly less awkward. Hmm...

Comment: Definitely consumes significantly more of your governors, but that may be an acceptable tradeoff depending on use case.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not sure if a for loop is possible as the parentIds need clearing immediately before the query... I've used this approach when creating a tree view because the relationships between the layers is explicit. But for collecting all the Accounts (assuming ~5 levels is enough), your ultimate parent approach is more elegant.

Comment: Posted a similar answer that could be adapted for this here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28521/apex-or-visualforce-way-to-get-a-list-of-queue-a-user-is-member-of/28527#28527 or a different version here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81603/users-hierarchy/81704#81704 both of which do not use a formal field however

Answer (score 3):

The key to any such functionality is an `Ultimate_Parent__c` function. I think it maxes out at ten levels deep, but here is a smaller example of how it should work:

```
BLANKVALUE(Parent.Parent.ParentId,
    BLANKVALUE(Parent.ParentId,
        BLANKVALUE(ParentId, Id
)))
```

Then, given any account, you can find its entire hierarchy using:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Ultimate_Parent__c = :originalAccount.Ultimate_Parent__c
```

You could limit this result to records below the original by adding a hierarchy depth formula along the lines of:

```
IF(Parent.Parent.ParentId != null, 3,
    IF(Parent.ParentId != null, 2,
        IF(ParentId != null, 1, 0
)))
```

And a query like:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account
WHERE Ultimate_Parent__c = :originalAccount.Ultimate_Parent__c
AND Hierarchy_Depth__c < :originalAccount.Hierarchy_Depth__c
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Could you show me an example of combing the formula with the hierarchy depth which you had shown above?